# How can I convert div that contains Dojox Gauge into image

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, dojo, html2canvas

In my application I'm using [Dojox Gauge](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojox/gauges.html). I need to convert that gauge into image. Dojo gauge is in div. I have tried so many ways. One way is convert **html2canvas** but than gauge is not visible after converting that div into canvas.

How to convert that component into image with JavaScript?

Comment: Perhaps this is of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790108/export-convert-chart-from-dojo-charting-to-image (the gauge has a surface property too, similar to charts)